# What's it called when the sum of individual numbers has the exact same digits as the total sum?

Tags: summation, exponentiation

e.g., what is the following expression an example of?

$2646798 = 2^1 + 6^2 + 4^3 + 6^4 + 7^5 + 9^6 + 8^7 $

Comment: How did you find this expression ?

Comment: It was shared with me as a meme

Comment: There is no name for this random phenomenon.

Comment: The list is finite: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 89, 135, 175, 518, 598, 1306, 1676, 2427, 2646798, 12157692622039623539 and doesn't seem to have a name. (ref: [OEIS A032799](https://oeis.org/A032799))

Comment: @achillehui interestingly the maple code is credited to Robert Israel, a user of this site...

Comment: Yeah it's probably made by observing that a number could only be on the list if the last digit is same parity to the number of odd digits ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called Disarium Numbers by [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-check-disarium-number) and [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disarium-number/). They can have at most 22 digits. I have checked first 19 ones in my computer.
They are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 89, 135, 175, 518, 598, 1306, 1676, 2427, 2646798 and 12157692622039623539.

They are equal to sum of each digit powered to it's digit position from beginning.

89 = 8^1 + 9^2 = 8 + 81

135 = 1^1 + 3^2 + 5^3 = 1 + 9 + 125

175 = 1^1 + 7^7 + 5^3 = 1 + 49 + 125

518 = 5^1 + 1^2 + 8^3 = 5 + 1 + 512

598 = 5^1 + 9^2 + 8^3 = 5 + 81 + 512